# Обновление+добавление новых данных в DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Существует некий DataFrame вида:

```
    ID  Name    inf1    inf2    inf3    inf4
0   11  qwe      q1      q2      q3      q4
1   12  asd      a1      a2      a3      a4
2   13  zxc      z1      z2      z3      z4
```

Далее загружается еще один DataFrame:

```
    ID  Name    inf1    inf2    inf3    inf4
0   11  qwe2     q1      q6      q3      q8
1   22  fgh      f1      f2      f3      f4
2   23  vbn      v1      v2      v3      v4
```

Где некоторые данные обновляются, и добавляются новые.
`ID` не меняется, его можно использовать в качестве индекса.
Результат должен быть таким:

```
    ID  Name    inf1    inf2    inf3    inf4
0   11  qwe2     q1      q6      q3      q8
1   12  asd      a1      a2      a3      a4
2   13  zxc      z1      z2      z3      z4
3   22  fgh      f1      f2      f3      f4
4   23  vbn      v1      v2      v3      v4
```

Я пробовал использовать `DataFrame.update()` - данные обновляются, но новые не добавляются.

Пробовал `DataFrame.merge()` - получается обновить данные, но опять же, не получается добавить новые.

Подскажите, можно ли как то лаконично обновлять имеющиеся значения по `ID` и добавлять новые, если такого `ID` нет в исходной таблице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [70]: d1 = (d2.append(d1[~d1['ID'].isin(d2['ID'])])
                 .sort_values('ID')
                 .reset_index(drop=True))

In [71]: d1
Out[71]:
   ID  Name inf1 inf2 inf3 inf4
0  11  qwe2   q1   q6   q3   q8
1  12   asd   a1   a2   a3   a4
2  13   zxc   z1   z2   z3   z4
3  22   fgh   f1   f2   f3   f4
4  23   vbn   v1   v2   v3   v4
```